# Manipulator not visible on selected rig controls

Tags: animation

I am using the following rig:

https://agora.community/content/spider-gwen-blender

I have linked the rig into a new scene, and made a library override. When I select any control other than the world controller, the gizmo/manipulator is not visible, for translate or rotate. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own solution, I had to select the RIG - SpiderGwen in the collection under Rig, enable Pose mode and then hide the bones/joints.